# Получение кадра из QMediaPlayer. Не срабатывает сигнал videoFrameProbed

Tags: c++, qt, видео

Почему не срабатывает сигнал videoFrameProbed

```
 player = new QMediaPlayer();
   vw = new QVideoWidget;
   probe = new QVideoProbe;
 probe->setSource(player);
   connect(probe, SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(const QVideoFrame &)), this, SLOT(processFrame( const QVideoFrame &)));
    way = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "", tr("Video Files (*.mp4));"));
     player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(way));
     player->play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению фреймворк `QtMultimedia` пока ещё не соответствует тому качеству реализации, каковое хотелось бы видеть. Обилие составляющих его классов со всякими интересными плюшками ничего в итоге не даёт, т.к. в большинстве своём они или не работают совсем или работают... э-э-э... местами. Ситуация с `QVideoProbe` - это как раз такой случай. Впрочем, комментарий в справке от самих же разработчиков вполне себе красноречив:

> probe->setSource(player); // Returns true, hopefully.

Поэтому, если нужен доступ к видеокадрам, обратитесь к C API ffmpeg, либо другому иному фреймворку, обладающему требуемым функционалом.